# Javascript several keyboard events

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keyboard-events

I'm currently building a music player with three buttons (actually simple divs) for Play/Pause (id="play"), Previous (id=rew) and Next (id="fwd").

I want the Play/Pause to be "clicked" when pressing SPACEBAR.
I want the Previous to be "clicked" when pressing LEFT ARROW.
I want the Next to be "clicked" when pressing RIGHT ARROW.

I've successfully managed the SPACEBAR control of Play with this :

```
var play = document.getElementById("play");

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        play.click();
    }
};
```

However, when I add the same for the two other buttons in my script, the SPACEBAR control of Play does not work anymore, as well as the other two.

So, what I have currently in my script and which is obviously not working is this :

```
<script>
var play = document.getElementById("play");

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        play.click();
    }
}; 


var rew = document.getElementById("rew");

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        rew.click();
    }
}; 

var fwd = document.getElementById("fwd");

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        fwd.click();
    }
}; 
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: addEventListener is the way to add events...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your keydown events is overwriting the previous one.

Instead, put all the logic into one keydown event, like this:

```
var play = document.getElementById("play");
var rew = document.getElementById("rew");
var fwd = document.getElementById("fwd");

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    play.click();
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    rew.click();
  } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    fwd.click();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign to `onkeydown` several times only the last one will be assigned because it will override the previous one. You can use `addEventListener` instead but that isn't the best approach neither. Just make more test inside one event listener like this:

```
var play = document.getElementById("play");
var rew = document.getElementById("rew");
var fwd = document.getElementById("fwd");

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        play.click();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 32) {
        rev.click();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 32) {
        fwd.click();
    }
};
```